# Passing by pointer-reference in blueprints with C++ definitions

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints

MyFunction( Class *& foo )

Inside a derivative BP of the above C++ class:

`foo` shows up as an output rather than an input.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-`const` references in C++ functions exposed to Blueprint are always treated as outputs by the parser in UnrealHeaderTool.

You can see this in the (very involved) logic of `FHeaderParser::GetVarType` in `Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealHeaderTool/Private/HeaderParser.cpp`. This is called by `ParseParameterList` during parsing a functions parameter list.

If you want `foo` to be an input, add `const` (this is what functions like [`RandomFloatFromRangeInStream`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Random/RandomFloatinRangefromStream/index.html) do to facilitate passing the heavyweight stream parameter as an input).

You cannot make it simultaneously an input and an output parameter.